# How to visualize the holonormic constraint $(\vec r_i - \vec r_j)^2 - c_{ij}^2$ = 0

Tags: classical-mechanics

A holonormic $(\vec r_i - \vec r_j)^2 - c_{ij}^2$ = 0 appears in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics Pg 12.

Where $i$, and $j$ are particles, however $c_{ij}$ is not defined.

How someone deduce the physical meaning of this constraint?

Comment: It means the distance between each pair of particles $i$ and $j$ is fixed to be a number, which we happen to be calling $c_{ij}$.

Comment: So to define rigid body...doh now I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the distance between each pair of particles $i$ and $j$ is fixed to be a number, which we happen to call $c_{ij}$. In other words, it describes a rigid body.